# The procedure entry point _wsplitpath_s could not be locating in the dynamic link library msvcrt.dll

Tags: c++, mfc, msvcrt

Recently upgrade a MFC++ Project which includes .NET assemblies from Visual Studio 2005 to 2008.
Now whenever its installed it displays the following message:

> The procedure entry point
>   _wsplitpath _s could not be locating in the dynamic link library msvcrt.dll

I've install Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86), still no luck.
And google didn't prove to be very helpful either.

Comment: Verify that you have the file api-ms-win-core-crt-l1-1-0.dll on your system https://www.opendll.com/index.php?search=+_wsplitpath_s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following URLs may be of interest to you...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166245.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/jameslau/archive/2008/02/13/upgrading-vs-2005-packages-to-vs-2008-a-more-advanced-guide.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/quanto/archive/2008/02/19/migrating-vs-2005-packages-to-vs-2008.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/quanto/archive/2008/01/19/migrating-from-vs-2005-to-vs-2008-with-microsoft-visualstudio-shell-references.aspx